# Internals of Network traffic capturing

Tags: c++, windows, networking, https, operating-system

I am working on project similar to HTTP Analyzer. I tried to capture network traffic using API hooking to WS2_32.dll.

It seems that we are only able to get the HTTP and HTTPS traffic from "native" application only but not the HTTPS traffic from "byte code" application(i.e. C#).

Please let me know if some one has knowledge of how the byte code application do the https communication and on which point/dll we can intercept that.

Appreciated any pointers or suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.winpcap.org/ may be a better place than Stack Overflow for you to begin. At the very least it should help you direct and narrow down your question.

Comment: A wild guess - the hook is x86 and the app is jitted to x86-64?